# $sum a field in an array - Query that results documents above a certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I created the following schema :

```
const videoSchema = createSchema(
    link: Type.string({required: true}),  
    description: Type.string({required: true}),
    answers: Type.array({required: true}).of({
         text: Type.string(), 
         likes: Type.number()
    })
);
export const videoModel = typedModel('video', videoSchema);
```

Now I want to write a query that only has videos with over 200 likes as a result. I've tried to work with `.aggregate`, `$reduce` and `$sum`, but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
/** Add a field which holds count of likes for all answers for a video */
{
    $addFields: {
        likesCount: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$answers.likes",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                    $add: [
                        "$$value",
                        "$$this"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
/** filter to retain videos whose likes > 200 */
{
    $match: {
        likesCount: {
            $gt: 200
        }
    }
},
/** Remove additional field from documents */
{
    $project: {
        likesCount: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kC6HxgdX2b1)

Comment: Instead of `$reduce: {...}` I would simply use `likesCount: {$sum: "$answers.likes"}` Do I miss anything?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Yes correct you could simply do :: `db.collection.find([
  {
    $expr: {
      $gt: [
        {
          $sum: "$answers.likes"
        },
        200
      ]
    }
  }
])` :-)

Comment: schema is unclear; answers.likes is a number type.  is the number the complete aggregate i.e. 200 ? or is it a single factor i.e. 1 that must be sum on a grouping by description?